# Acer_wmi blocking my wifi

Tags: networking, drivers

Every time I log in I have to type "sudo rmmod acer_wmi" to get wifi to work. How do I get this to run on startup or permanantly delete acer_wmi.

Thx

Comment: Your driver found and loaded firmware and created an interface: wlp8s0. Is the switch or key combination set to enable wireless? `rfkill list all`? What is the trouble you are having specifically?

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 7):

Edit the blacklist:

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

And add the faulty module there (at the end):

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

reboot and voilà

Comment: Thanks so much, @lupa. That worked perfectly to enable the onboard Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX 201 module in an HP Pavilion x360 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You can blacklist that module. It is convenient to make a separate file. Run in terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

Answer (score 1):

​I realize I'm replying to this question rather late, but there's another method I've used when booting into liveUSBs. Since there is no easy way to edit their `/etc/modprobe.d/` after creating the USB, add this snippet when you see the kernel selection screen add this by pressing `[tab]`

```
modprobe.blacklist=acer_wmi
```

Whether this gets carried over from the liveUSB to the distro once it's been installed can be hit or miss. If it doesn't, adding this parameter to `/etc/default/grub` on the line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`

Now every time you boot it'll be blacklisted!

I'm not always the best at explaining things like this so if you need clarification please let me know.